# Is it possible that writing a site on an online editor is a problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I made a small todolist site, and I have created the code of this website on an online editor everything is fine for the moment, but once loaded on visual code studio and tested with another software the site does not work, practically when I go to insert an inscription in the text field by pressing the 'enter' key should be added to the list as a to-do but I don't know why it doesn't work if I press the enter button nothing happens while on the online editor everything was working perfectly.
Excuse me I'm not very expert on this but I can't find the problem prorpio

```js
$(function(){

    // Todo Model
    // ----------
  
    // Our basic **Todo** model has `title`, `order`, and `done` attributes.
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  
      // Default attributes for the todo item.
      defaults: function() {
        return {
          title: "empty todo...",
          order: Todos.nextOrder(),
          done: false
        };
      },
  
      // Toggle the `done` state of this todo item.
      toggle: function() {
        this.save({done: !this.get("done")});
      }
  
    });
  
    // Todo Collection
    // ---------------
  
    // The collection of todos is backed by *localStorage* instead of a remote
    // server.
    var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  
      // Reference to this collection's model.
      model: Todo,
  
      // Save all of the todo items under the `"todos-backbone"` namespace.
      localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-backbone"),
  
      // Filter down the list of all todo items that are finished.
      done: function() {
        return this.where({done: true});
      },
  
      // Filter down the list to only todo items that are still not finished.
      remaining: function() {
        return this.without.apply(this, this.done());
      },
  
      // We keep the Todos in sequential order, despite being saved by unordered
      // GUID in the database. This generates the next order number for new items.
      nextOrder: function() {
        if (!this.length) return 1;
        return this.last().get('order') + 1;
      },
  
      // Todos are sorted by their original insertion order.
      comparator: 'order'
  
    });
  
    // Create our global collection of **Todos**.
    var Todos = new TodoList;
  
    // Todo Item View
    // --------------
  
    // The DOM element for a todo item...
    var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  
      //... is a list tag.
      tagName:  "li",
  
      // Cache the template function for a single item.
      template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
  
      // The DOM events specific to an item.
      events: {
        "click .toggle"   : "toggleDone",
        "dblclick #view"  : "edit",
        "click a.destroy" : "clear",
        "keypress .edit"  : "updateOnEnter",
        "blur .edit"      : "close"
      },
  
      // The TodoView listens for changes to its model, re-rendering. Since there's
      // a one-to-one correspondence between a **Todo** and a **TodoView** in this
      // app, we set a direct reference on the model for convenience.
      initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
      },
  
      // Re-render the titles of the todo item.
      render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
        this.input = this.$('.edit');
        return this;
      },
  
      // Toggle the `"done"` state of the model.
      toggleDone: function() {
        this.model.toggle();
      },
  
      // Switch this view into `"editing"` mode, displaying the input field.
      edit: function() {
        this.$el.addClass("editing");
        this.input.focus();
      },
  
      // Close the `"editing"` mode, saving changes to the todo.
      close: function() {
        var value = this.input.val();
        if (!value) {
          this.clear();
        } else {
          this.model.save({title: value});
          this.$el.removeClass("editing");
        }
      },
  
      // If you hit `enter`, we're through editing the item.
      updateOnEnter: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) this.close();
      },
  
      // Remove the item, destroy the model.
      clear: function() {
        this.model.destroy();
      }
  
    });
  
    // The Application
    // ---------------
  
    // Our overall **AppView** is the top-level piece of UI.
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  
      // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
      // the App already present in the HTML.
      el: $("#todoapp"),
  
      // Our template for the line of statistics at the bottom of the app.
      statsTemplate: _.template($('#stats-template').html()),
  
      // Delegated events for creating new items, and clearing completed ones.
      events: {
        "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter",
        "click #clear-completed": "clearCompleted"
        
      },
  
      // At initialization we bind to the relevant events on the `Todos`
      // collection, when items are added or changed. Kick things off by
      // loading any preexisting todos that might be saved in *localStorage*.
      initialize: function() {
  
        this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
        this.allCheckbox = this.$("#toggle-all")[0];
  
        this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(Todos, 'reset', this.addAll);
        this.listenTo(Todos, 'all', this.render);
  
        this.footer = this.$('footer');
        this.main = $('#main');
  
        Todos.fetch();
      },
  
      // Re-rendering the App just means refreshing the statistics -- the rest
      // of the app doesn't change.
      render: function() {
        var done = Todos.done().length;
        var remaining = Todos.remaining().length;
  
        if (Todos.length) {
          this.main.show();
          this.footer.show();
          this.footer.html(this.statsTemplate({done: done, remaining: remaining}));
        } else {
          this.main.hide();
          this.footer.hide();
        }
  
        
      },
  
      // Add a single todo item to the list by creating a view for it, and
      // appending its element to the `<ul>`.
      addOne: function(todo) {
        var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
        this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
      },
  
      // Add all items in the **Todos** collection at once.
      addAll: function() {
        Todos.each(this.addOne, this);
      },
  
      // If you hit return in the main input field, create new **Todo** model,
      // persisting it to *localStorage*.
      createOnEnter: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
        if (!this.input.val()) return;
  
        Todos.create({title: this.input.val()});
        this.input.val('');
      },
  
      // Clear all done todo items, destroying their models.
      clearCompleted: function() {
        _.invoke(Todos.done(), 'destroy');
        return false;
      }
  
      
  
    });
  
    // Finally, we kick things off by creating the **App**.
    var App = new AppView;
  
  });
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Cpath d="M8 16c4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8-8 3.582-8 8 3.582 8 8 8zm0-2c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zm33.414-6l5.95-5.95L45.95.636 40 6.586 34.05.636 32.636 2.05 38.586 8l-5.95 5.95 1.414 1.414L40 9.414l5.95 5.95 1.414-1.414L41.414 8zM40 48c4.418 0 8-3.582 8-8s-3.582-8-8-8-8 3.582-8 8 3.582 8 8 8zm0-2c3.314 0 6-2.686 6-6s-2.686-6-6-6-6 2.686-6 6 2.686 6 6 6zM9.414 40l5.95-5.95-1.414-1.414L8 38.586l-5.95-5.95L.636 34.05 6.586 40l-5.95 5.95 1.414 1.414L8 41.414l5.95 5.95 1.414-1.414L9.414 40z" fill="%239C92AC" fill-opacity="0.4" fill-rule="evenodd"/%3E%3C/svg%3E'); 
      color: black;
      font-family: space grotesk;
    background-color: black;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin: 8px auto;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  
  *:focus{outline:none !important;}
  
  #openlist{
   position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 3%;
   font-family: space grotesk;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid white;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  #openlist:hover{
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border: solid #E0E0E0;
  }
  
  #openlist:active{
  transform: scale(0.90);
  }
  
  
  #todoapp {
      background: black;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      margin:0px auto;
      width: 300px;
  
  }
  
  #todoapp h2 {
      
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: white;
      border-bottom:1px solid black;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      color: black;
      font-family: space grotesk;
      font-size:16px;
      font-weight: 100;
      line-height: 56px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin:0;
  }
  
  
  
  #todoapp ul, #todoapp li {
      list-style: none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
  
  #todoapp li {
  
      background-color: white;
      border-bottom:1px solid black;
      color: black;
  
  }
  
  #todoapp li span{
      margin-left:30px;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
      -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
      -o-transition: all .2s linear;
      transition: all .2s linear;   
  }
  
  #todoapp label{
  
      cursor:pointer;
      display:block;
      line-height: 56px;
      padding: 0 15px; 
      position: relative;
  
  }
  
  #todoapp li:hover {
  
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      color:black;
  
  }
  
  #todoapp input[type="text"] {
      background-color: white;
      border-top:1px solid black;
      border-bottom:none;
      border-left:none;
      border-right:none;
      color: black;
      font-size:14px;
      margin:0;
      padding:20px 15px;
      width:270px;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
      -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
      -o-transition: all .2s linear;
      transition: all .2s linear;
      font-family: space grotesk;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      -ms-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      -o-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      
  }
  
  #todoapp input[type="text"]:hover{
      color: black;
  }
  
  #todoapp input[type="text"]:focus{
      color:black;
  }
  
  #todoapp ::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: grey;} /* WebKit browsers */
  
  
  #main {
      display: none;
  }
  
  #todo-list {
      
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      max-height:227px;
  }
  
  #todo-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
  }
  
  #todo-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
      
      background-color: white;
      
  }
  
  #todo-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
      height: 6px;
      background-color: #212121;

  }
  
  #todo-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
      width: 6px;
      background-color: #212121;

  }
  
  #todo-list li {
      
      position: relative;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      border-right: 1px solid white;
  }
  
  #todo-list li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
  }
  
  #todo-list  input.toggle[type="checkbox"]{
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
  }
  
  #todo-list input.toggle[type="checkbox"] + i {
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: block;
      height: 16px;
      position: absolute;
      top:20px;
      width: 16px;  
      z-index: 1;
  }
  .destroy {
  
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-color: #de3f53;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
      float: right;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: normal;
      height: 17px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 17px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 15px;
      top: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
      -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
      -o-transition: all .2s linear;
      transition: all .2s linear;
  
  }
  
  #todo-list  input.toggle[type="checkbox"]:checked + i::after{
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 8px;
      left: 4px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      width: 8px;
      z-index: 2;
  }
  
  #todo-list li.done label {
      color: grey;
      text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  
  
  
  #todo-list li:hover .destroy {
        display: block;
      
  }
  
  #todo-list .destroy:hover {
    background-position: 0 -20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #de3f53;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  #todo-list li.editing {
      border-bottom: none;
      margin-top: -1px;
      padding: 0;
      border-right: 1px solid white;
  }
  
  #todo-list li.editing:last-child {
      margin-bottom: -1px;
  }
  
  #todo-list li.editing .edit {
      display: block;
      width:263px;
      border-bottom:1px solid white;
      border-top:1px solid white;
      border-left:none;
      border-right:none;
      padding: 20px 15px 21px 15px;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
      -ms-border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
      -o-border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
      border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
      
  }
  
  #todo-list li.editing .view {
      display: none;
  }
  
  #todo-list li .view label {
      word-break: break-word;
  }
  
  #todo-list li .edit {
      display: none;
  }
  
  
  
  #todoapp footer {
      display: none;
      position:relative;
      top:-5px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: black;
      background: white;
      line-height: 30px;
      padding-left:10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      -ms-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      -o-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  }
  
  #clear-completed {
      float: right;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      font-size: 11px;
      margin-top: 6px;
  
      margin-right: 4px;
      padding: 0 10px 0px;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      -ms-border-radius: 12px;
      -o-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 40px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  
  }
  
  #clear-completed:hover {
      background: white;
    color: black;
  }
  
  #clear-completed:active {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
  }
  
  #todo-count span {
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  
  #dragme{
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 39%;
  }
  
  #closeTDL {
  
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      background-color: black;
      color: black;
      font-family: space grotesk;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-top:4px;
      float:right;
      
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="theme-color" content="white">
<link rel="icon" href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAyfifMxk7ZlZQCGOSLyfLeqjaCrEH6Xzqu_LLu3oSQJxAIeLkx3cPB2lm3OAUAsQKJJw&usqp=CAU">
<title>To do list</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Grotesk:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
        </style>
     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.16/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>


&nbsp;<button href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('dragme');" id="openlist">Toggle To Do List</button> 





      <div id="dragme">
      


   <div id="todoapp"><a href="#" id="closeTDL"  onclick="toggle_visibility('dragme');" style="color:white;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:none;">➖&nbsp;</a>


<div>

  <h2><strong>TO DO LIST</strong></h2>
<section id="main">
    
    <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
  
  
  </section>
  <header>
    
    <input id="new-todo" type="text" placeholder="Write new item and hit 'Enter'...">
  
  </header>

  

  <footer>

    <a id="clear-completed" >Clear completed</a>
    <div id="todo-count"></div>
  </footer>

</div>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
  <div class="view">
    
    <label><input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= done ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %> /><i></i><span title="Double-click to edit a todo."><%- title %></span></label>
    <a class="destroy">&minus;</a>
  </div>
  <input class="edit" type="text" value="<%- title %>" />
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="stats-template">
  <% if (done) { %>
    <a id="clear-completed">Clear <%= done %> completed <%= done == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %></a>
  <% } %>
  <div class="todo-count"><b><%= remaining %></b> <%= remaining == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %> left</div>
</script>
    
    </div>     
    
<script type="text/javascript">

  function toggle_visibility(id) {
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if(e.style.display == 'none')
        e.style.display = 'block';
     else
        e.style.display = 'none';
  }

</script>



<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dragme" ).draggable({ iframeFix: true });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I start it here it gives me the error but I don't understand what it is

Comment: First rule of troubleshooting - use your web inspector. When I look at it after running this code, I see `backbone.localStorage.js:137 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.` - you can't utilize localStorage inside the snippet sandbox here.